# Encrypting Source Code

Tags: obfuscation, encrypting-file-system

I work on relatively sensitive code that we wouldn't want falling into the wrong hands. Up until now, all the code has been keep in house so it hasn't been an issue. I am moving to working from home a day or two a week and we want to secure the code on my laptop.

We have looked at a few alternatives, but Windows EFS and Bitlocker seem to be the most obvious. The laptop doesn't have TPM hardware, and I won't have access to Active Directory from home, so EFS looks to be the option.

Basically, does anyone else have any alternatives, or issues with using EFS to encrypt source code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/downloads.php):

> **WARNING: Using TrueCrypt is not secure as it may contain unfixed security issues**
>
> This page exists only to help migrate existing data encrypted by TrueCrypt.
>
> The development of TrueCrypt was ended in 5/2014 after Microsoft terminated support of Windows XP. Windows 8/7/Vista and later offer integrated support for encrypted disks and virtual disk images. Such integrated support is also available on other platforms (click [here](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/OtherPlatforms.html) for more information). You should migrate any data encrypted by TrueCrypt to encrypted disks or virtual disk images supported on your platform...

Comment: Agreed. An encrypted TrueCrypt partition should also be fast enough not to slow down compilation process etc..

Comment: Just be sure to place the page file also on that partition.

Comment: You can also set windows to clear the pagefile on shutdown instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/). It's free, open source and supported on a number of platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend [Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The last time I did this was a few years ago, but we used PGPdisk. It did a good job.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/). It would accomplish the same thing, and be a bit less invasive to your system.

Answer (score 0):

TrueCrypt, there's no excuse to use anything different.  It's secure and it's free...what more could you want.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for TrueCrypt. We use it at work, it's great.

Tip: it seems that if you have a big codebase and you work with multiple working copies checked out simultaneously, you get much better performance if each working copy is on its own encrypted partition.

Answer (score 0):

You MAY want to encrypt PARTS of the data instead of all of it for speed and simplification issues, however, using a windows encrypted volume would be fairly easy as well. Don't forget that if you must encrypt the entire source, then remember that you're best off encrypting the entire development machine, not just a single volume as temp files or swap files may contain the decrypted information.